# Knockout - Unable to process binding

Tags: javascript, wordpress, knockout.js

I am pulling my hair out with this one as I can't seem to get knockout working properly. I am using knockout on a wordpress theme. I wrote a knockout viewmodel which is a bit complex and it did work but all of sudden today it started giving me the error `Unable to process binding`. So I just created a very simple Knockout viewmodel to make sure that my original code is not the cause of the issue. And its still giving me the same error. Below is what I have for testing purposes:

**Script:**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bob";
    this.lastName = "Dylan";
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('test'));
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="row" id="test">
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName">N/A</strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName">N/A</strong></p>
</div>
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return firstName }"
Message: firstName is not defined
```

I have knockout and my script file loading in the Wordpress `functions.php` file and they both seem to be loading fine when I checked the browser. This is everything I can think of including here. I am sure there is nothing wrong with the code I posted above and there is something else causing the issue so if you need me to provide more information please ask. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: For debugging purpose, can you remove your <p>'s and add this code: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre> ?

Comment: Do you have another ko.applyBindings somewhere in the document?

Comment: @JesusAngulo Looks like ko has some different data on `$data` from another plugin.

Comment: @FabioLuz I didnt write any other ko.applyBindings but looks like theres another plugin that uses KO

Comment: code looks clear if you can setup a fiddle explaining your issue that would be great .

Comment: @balbzr try to edit the plugin's code and make sure it is binding to a specific node

Comment: I create a jsfiddle from your code and everything seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/appfqs8y/ Maybe jQuery is not available, so the binding will never happen?

Comment: Same for me, created a fiddle (without jquery usage tho) https://jsfiddle.net/bwhpjwy3/ Seems to work fine.